# can not read property 'arrayOfDay1' of null

Tags: react-native

how to fix it?

i check array  not null and go to if

but my app get error

```
   if (this.state.arrayOfDay1.length === 0 || this.state.arrayOfDay1 === 'undefined') {
            console.log(18);
                var result = (this.state.arrayOfDay1).includes(i + 1);
                if (result === true) {
                    state = 1;
                    // pic = require('../upload/see.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/see.png') });
                    // this.setState({ key: true });
                } else {
                    state = 0;
                    // pic = require('../upload/notSee.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/notSee.png') });
                }

        }else {
            state = 0;
            console.log(1115);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQWio.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYpWG.jpg)

thanks

:))))

edited

i find my problem.
i forgot to insert this before state

nicccce

Comment: change the condition. You make the condition to enter if condition when the array is empty or undefined. Reverse the condition and it will work fine

Comment: (this.state.arrayOfDay1.length != 0 && this.state.arrayOfDay1 != undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to

```
if (this.state.arrayOfDay1.length != 0 && this.state.arrayOfDay1 != undefined && this.state.arrayOfDay1.length != null) {
            console.log(18);
                var result = (this.state.arrayOfDay1).includes(i + 1);
                if (result === true) {
                    state = 1;
                    // pic = require('../upload/see.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/see.png') });
                    // this.setState({ key: true });
                } else {
                    state = 0;
                    // pic = require('../upload/notSee.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/notSee.png') });
                }

        }else {
            state = 0;
            console.log(1115);
        }
```

Comment: not work...  null is not an object ( evaluating '_this2.stat.arrayOfDay1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(this.state.arrayOfDay1.length !== 0 && this.state.arrayOfDay1 !== undefined ) {
            console.log(18);
                var result = (this.state.arrayOfDay1).includes(i + 1);
                if (result === true) {
                    state = 1;
                    // pic = require('../upload/see.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/see.png') });
                    // this.setState({ key: true });
                } else {
                    state = 0;
                    // pic = require('../upload/notSee.png');
                    // this.setState({ pic: require('../upload/notSee.png') });
                }

        }else {
            state = 0;
            console.log(1115);
        }
```